# Thymeleaf - Check if array contains element with property

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a list of `comments`. Each comment has an attribute `author`. And each author has a `username`.

I want to display a specific button only if the current user did not write a comment yet. (Which means there must be no comment in the list, where the username of the author equals user.username)

This is what it would look like in JavaScript:

```
if(!comments.some(comment => comment.author.username === user.username))
```

But I have no idea, how to do it in Thymeleaf. I could not find any necessary functions like array#map(), array#any(), etc. Inline loops also don't seem to be a thing.

```
 <button th:if="${!<What goes here?>}" class="btn btn-primary">Add Comment</button>
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a working solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34828280/10686377

Using Spring's [Collection Selection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-collection-selection) you can check if a list contains an element with a specific property value.

```
<button th:unless="${comments.^[author.username == user.username]}"  class="btn btn-primary">Add Comment</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this is will replicate some function of javascript

```
<div th:each="comment : ${comments}">
 <button th:if="${comment.author.username == user.username}" class="btn btn-primary">Add Comment</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It throws this error: `Could not parse as expression: "comment : ${comments}"`. I think this expression is only possible in th:each, but then it would give me multiple buttons. And the inner if is missing a negation, i only want the button to be there if the user did not write a comment yet.